# SiteCatalyst image request onreadystatechange

Tags: tags, analytics, adobe-analytics

Is there any possibility of "listening" to the state of GET SiteCatalyst image requests ?
I'd like to run a callback function only when the requests are over, to be more clear when they receive the 200 status code and I'm sure they're done.
I'm confident no "built-in" method is available and maybe I should hack the core *s.track.s.t()* function...?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is no global "built-in" callback method for when the Adobe Analytics request is complete.

A couple notes I should mention to you about attempting to hack the core code:

1) If you are using the AppMeasurement library version 1.4.1+, in some circumstances, [a POST request may be made](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/whatsnew/09182014.html) instead of an image request.

2) Responses that are not 200/OK or otherwise completed/successful does not necessarily mean the data failed to be sent to Adobe. Most common scenario is a [NS_BINDING_ABORTED error returned](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/debugger_ns_binding.html).

Comment: Thx @Crayon Violent, very helpful as usual. Indeed I'm trying to hack the core or, better saying, to mimic the Image Request as an Ajax one (GET). This would allow me to bind a callback. This would be conditioned to request's status and I'll be aware about NS_BINDING_ABORTED too. The only side effect I'm facing is a resulting double XHR request...

Answer (score 0):

The main bad effect I'm getting here is what I previously thought as a double XHR request.
It wasn't. In reality the first request gets redirected as it would be the first visit of a new visitor (302 status) and a new visitorID is brought down by Adobe server.
Then the redirected "200 status" request is made with this new visitorID within.
This is bad because every XHR requests would result in a new visit of a new visitor even though a previously set "s_vi" cookie is there in browser, with the lack of previous collected data for that user.
I know what XHR redirects couldn't be blocked so I'm wondering if there is a way to "tell" Adobe server it's not the first request ever made, in order to stop the redirect and do not use a new visitorID.